# Change styles in all Divs on Scroll Event | Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to change the padding of all the tags with same id on scroll. But only first tag is changing. Rest of the tags are not changing.

My view:

```
<a #nav> Home </a>
<a #nav> About </a>
<a #nav> Contact </a>
```

Only Home padding is changing.
TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare const window: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('nav')
  elementRef!: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



  //Sticky Menu
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(event: Event){ 
    const number = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    
    event.preventDefault();
    if (number > 300) {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty('padding', '19px 0px');
      console.log(this.elementRef);
    } else {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty('padding', '39px 0px');
    }
  }
  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) should be unique which will evaluate with the first element that holds it only.

What you are looking for is [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, QueryList, ViewChildren, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare const window: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChildren('nav') elementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



  //Sticky Menu
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(event: Event){ 
    const number = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    
    event.preventDefault();
    this.elementRefs.forEach((element: ElementRef) => {
    if (number > 300) {
      element.nativeElement.style.setProperty('padding', '19px 0px');
      console.log(element);
    } else {
      element.nativeElement.style.setProperty('padding', '39px 0px');
    }
    })
  }
  

}
```

Then you can loop through and set your styles.

Comment: >Property 'style' does not exist on type 'QueryList<ElementRef<any>>

Comment: I'm new in angular and don't know about loops in ts. Can you please right down all changes for me.

Comment: `QueryList` is an array-like, you need to loop through for example with [`forEach`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#foreach) and inside add the styles.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzaib I just update the answer, please check again.

Comment: the document is compiled but getting this error in console :
>this.elementRefs.forEach is not a function

Comment: @MuhammadShahzaib, Are you sure you get the last code I edit on the answer?

Comment: Yes its same. I checked it three times. only I initial elementRefs like this: ```@ViewChild('nav') elementRefs!: QueryList<ElementRef>;```

Comment: Sir, it's `@ViewChildren('nav') elementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>`, with `@ViewChildren` not `@ViewChild`, please copy paste the code on the answer.

Comment: Ohhh. My Mistake. I was checking only foreach. Thank you so much sir . it worked.

Comment: Never mind, have a good day.